# One row at the bottom outside of excel border, how to fix this?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to fix this little issue for a while but I cannot find a proper answer anywhere. Basically, I want a border that goes around my used cells. The table is huge and it works until it gets to the very last row, which is left out of said border.

Here is the code that takes care of the border:

```
Function Borders()
    Range(Range("A3"), Range("A3").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThick, Color:=vbBlack
    Range(Range("A4"), Range("A3").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThick, Color:=vbBlack
End Function
```

And this is what the very end of the looks like:

[image]

That is the very end of the last row. All that row is left out of the table. I don't really see what the issue might be.

Comment: Why have you created the function ?

Comment: The function is called in a much bigger function that does other modifications on the table: Reordering of columns, coloring etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your function ,

```
   With Range(Range("A4"), Range("A4").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThick
    .Color = vbBlack
   End With
```